# How do I change a singly-linked list to a doubly-linked list?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently taking a Java class and the professor told us that a good practice to understand links would be to make a doubly linked list. I have made a singly linked list but I am having trouble converting it to a doubly linked list. So I was wondering if anybody could give me any suggestions on making sure my last number is connected to the previous one? And if the front number and last number connected to the null. Here is part of the code, if you wish for more of it just ask and I shall post.

The code for adding elements and such. This is my attempt of trying to make the tail which is the end connect to the last number.

```
public void add(int element){

            Node n = new Node();
            n.setItem(element);
            n.setNext(head);
            head = n;
            >
            //The tail connected to the new number added.
            n.setItem(element);
            n.setBefore(tail);
            tail = n;
```

The code below is the insert function which I need to make sure the new inserted blocks connect but I'm having troubles thinking of a way to make it connect for both.

```
public void insert(int element, int position){

        int currentposition = 0;
        Node currentNode = head;

        //Traverse to the right position
        while(currentposition < position-1){

            currentposition++;
        } 
        Node n = new Node();
        n.setItem(element);
        n.setNext(currentNode.getNext());
        currentNode.setNext(n);

        //The previous number connecting to the new number
        currentNode = tail;

    }
```

Comment: Each node in the list should now have a `previous` reference.

Comment: Also you should have a reference to the `first`, and to the `last`

Comment: So I should add a reference to the previous node which in other words I should add a reference to my CurrentNode?

Comment: Your first (head) node should have `prev->null` and `next->[the next node]`. The next node should have `prev->head` and `next->[the next node or null]`

Comment: @nachokk: So I should reference the currentNode to the to the first Node and The last? Such as using the n.setNext() to be connected to the last and next Node?

Comment: `while(currentposition < position-1){ currentposition++; }` This is equivalent to `currentposition = position-1`. You need to do something at each iteration.

Comment: @Sotirios: So I should reference head to the null? and the next should reference the currentNode? Sorry If I'm not on target with your statements. I have only been doing Java for a short amount of time.

Comment: @Cruncher: I understand, I'm still pretty new to Java myself so I'm not the best at it yet.I understand that I need to do some iteration but first I want to make it a doubly linked before making any iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You add an extra Node field to each Node that holds its previous Node

Insertion Pseudocode:

```
insert(Node n, index i) {
    currentIndex = 0
    currentNode = head
    while (currentIndex < i) {
      currentNode = currentNode.next
      currentIndex++
    }
    n.prev = currentNode
    n.next = currentNode.next
    currentNode.next = n
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For doubly linked list, you need to add both head and tail fields in the class so that it maintains a doubly linked data structure.

```
private Node<T> head = null;
private Node<T> tail = head;
private int size = 0;
```

To add a new node to the end of the linked list, you can do

```
public void add(T element) {
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(element);
    Node<T> current = head;
    if(current == null) {
        current = node;
        head = tail = current;
    } else {
        tail.next = node;
        node.prev = tail;
        tail = node;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Note that you also need to deal with the empty list case which is the first if clause. Also you can set next and prev references for tail when you add the node.

To insert a node to the list at a certain position, you need to consider that if the specified position is less than 0 or great than the existing list size, then error occurs because you can't insert element with out of bound index. So you can throw exception. Also you need to separate the case when the inserted position is at `0` (`head`) or at `size` (`tail`). Considering all these cases, the solution is:

```
public void insert(T a, int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(a);
    Node<T> temp;
    if(position == 0) {
        if(head == null)
            add(a);
        else {
            temp = head;
            head = node;
            node.next = temp;
            temp.prev = node;
        }
        return;
    } else if (position == size) {
        temp = tail;
        tail = node;
        temp.next = tail;
        tail.prev = temp;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while (current != null && i < position-1) {
        current = current.next;
        i++;
    }

    temp = current.next;
    current.next = node;
    node.prev = current;
    node.next = temp;
    temp.prev = node;
}
```